# Dismiss ZSH completion list after typing a character

Tags: macos, shell, autocomplete, zsh

In Fish shell when you press tab, list of completions is shown and if you start typing again it id dismissed

[image: Fish dismissing auto-completion list]

In ZSH after I star typing the completion menu is still shown and useless

[image: ZSH not dismissing auto-completion list]

Is there a way to make ZSH auto-completion behave the same way as Fish, so dismissing the list after typing?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this? If so please post it I would love to have it in my config.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get this behavior with ZSH 5.7.1.

This is what's in my zshrc:

```
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit

source $SOFTWARE_HOME/zinit/bin/zinit.zsh
autoload -Uz _zinit
(( ${+_comps} )) && _comps[zinit]=_zinit
zinit ice depth=1; zinit light romkatv/powerlevel10k
zinit light zdharma/fast-syntax-highlighting
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-completions
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search

setopt glob_complete
setopt menu_complete
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
bindkey '^[[A' history-substring-search-up
bindkey '^[[B' history-substring-search-down
export HISTORY_SUBSTRING_SEARCH_HIGHLIGHT_FOUND=(none)
```

These are my options:

```
❯ setopt
combiningchars
extendedglob
extendedhistory
globcomplete
histfindnodups
incappendhistory
interactive
login
menucomplete
monitor
promptsubst
pushdsilent
shinstdin
zle
```

Comment: You config seems to automatically select the first completion

Comment: Yes, you're post says you want to "auto-complete". <Tab> selects the next item in the list. <Esc><back-space> closes the completion menu

Comment: Not really, even the title says dismissing after typing a character not completing

Answer (score 0):

AUTO_MENU :    which Automatically use menu completion after the second consecutive request for completion, for example by pressing the tab key repeatedly

MENU_COMPLETE :    On an ambiguous completion, instead of listing possibilities or beeping, insert the first match immediately. Then when completion is requested again, remove the  first match and insert the second match, etc. When there are no more matches, go back to the first one again

zsh defaults to AUTO_MENU.

if you change it to MENU_AUTOCOMPLETE with `setopt menu_complete` then it will work almost like fish.

to autoload this setting just save it to your .zshrc config file.

if you want additional information about options you can go to zsh options manual `man zshoptions`.